# Intuition behind the $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$ Kuratowski closure axiom in general topology?

Tags: general-topology, intuition

If we use the real numbers as a model of topology (with the standard topology), then it is obvious why $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$ should hold, given the definition of "closure of a set" in the context of the real numbers.

But what a good intuition for why this axiom should hold in the context of general topology?

I have an intuition for all 3 other axioms:

1. $cl(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ (intuition: no objects touch the empty set, because you can't touch a set consisting of no objects)
2. $A\subseteq cl(A)$ (intuition: every element of $A$ touches $A$, because elements "touch themselves").
3. $cl(A\cup B) = cl(A)\cup cl(B)$ (intuition: if an object touches a set consisting of two parts, then it must at least touch one of those parts, because if you don't touch either of two things, you can't suddenly touch the combination of the two).
4. $cl(cl(A))=cl(A)$ (intuition: if a set of objects $B$ all touch $A$, then any object that touches $B$ must also touch $A$, but this doesn't feel right to me. it feels too restrictive).

**What is a good intuition for why nr 4 should hold for topologies, given that topologies formalize the notion of "touch-relations"?**

Comment: If you think about closure of $A$ as set of limit points of $A$, then it's obvious that limit points of a closure of $A$ should be the same set. You cannot get bigger, you're already at the peak

Comment: @Jakobian, Could you explain this relation between limit points and "bigger"/"you're stuck at the peak"? The definition of limit point of $A$ as I know it is simply the set of points that "touch" $A$, and this has nothing to do with "optimality" or "size" afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\cl{cl}$In terms of metric spaces, the statement "$x\in\cl(A)$" that you want to think of as "$x$ touches $A$" becomes "the distance of $x$ to $A$ is $0$". Here the distance $x$ has to $A$ is defined as
$$
\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = \inf_{a\in A} d(x,a).
$$
Now take $x\in\cl(\cl(A))$ and let's figure out what this means in terms of distance. The point $x$ has a distance of $0$ to the set of all points having distance $0$ to $A$. Now in general for three points $x,y,z$ we have
$$
d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(x,z).
$$
So if $x$ has distance $0$ to all points $y$ having distance $0$ to $A$, these distances will at most sum up and $x$ has distance at most $0+0=0$ to $A$. We conclude that $x$ is indeed touching $A$ and hence
$$
\cl(\cl(A)) \subseteq \cl(A).
$$
The other inclusion is given by property 2.

Comment: I like this answer, but I would like it even more if we could somehow get the same "intuitive point" while abstracting away from "distance", since obviously "distance" assumes more structure than topology. ( I understand why you invoke it though, since it is clarifying).

Comment: Well you take your intuition from what properties the closure operators of metric spaces satisfy and then just call $X$ with a closure operator satisfying the same properties a topological space. This is just how abstraction works, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's *bad* per se, but it still intuitively relies on the concept metric spaces, which gives me the sense that the intuition is not as general as it might be. But don't get me wrong, I still like the idea.

Comment: Also, while measuring distance between two points *does* need more structure than just a topology, deciding whether the distance of $x$ and $A$ is *zero* does not! I guess that's the whole point: you loose an absolute notion of distance, but you keep a notion of touching, i.e., having distance $0$.

Comment: interesting. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the "distance 0" I think doesn't capture the fully general case of a topological space, because this so called "distance" can be asymmetric. e.g. take a finite poset $(X,\leq)$, and define the topology, where $U$ is open iff for all $a\in X/U$, and all $b\in U$ we have $a< b$. Then $a$ may touch $b$ without $b$ touching $a$.  In that case we can't really talk of the distance = $0$ idea, right?

Comment: We are talking about the distance between a point and a subspace, of course this is not symmetric. But yes: in metric spaces the distance between $x$ and $\{y\}$ is zero if and only if the distance between $y$ and $\{x\}$ is zero. This does not carry over to non-Hausdorff topological spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Property 4 is called idempotence. It means after one application, it doesn't matter how many more is applied. You are providing "closure" axioms. Therefore once a subset is closed, it should not change after more "closure" applications

Comment: This is not an answer. This is just a restatement of the axiom.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't know what a closure operator is. For more insight, see <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator>. A closure operator becomes a topological closure once the union axiom is invoked. Cheers!

Comment: for operators which are not idempotent, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preclosure_operator